# Solving integral with generic pdf

Tags: integral

I have a continuously differentiable function $h:[\underline{x},\overline{x}] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and a continuous random variable $X$ distributed according to a cdf $F$, with full support on $[\underline{x},\overline{x}]$. We know that $h(\underline{x})=0$. I am trying to solve the differential equation
$$2h'(x)h(x)=x$$
Integrating both sides
$$2\int_{\underline{x}}^xh'(t)h(t)f(t)dt=\int_{\underline{x}}^xxf(t)dt$$
I solved the problem in the case where $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[\underline{x},\overline{x}]$, using integration by parts, and I got
$$h(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2-\underline{x}}{2}}$$
However, I was not able to replicate the reasoning in the general case, nor express $h(x)$ in terms of $F(x)$ or its moments in a more explicit way. I was wondering if there is anything more we can get out of this formula, without making specific assumptions about the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Your differential equation has nothing to do with $X$!  What are you assuming about the relationship between $h$ and $F$??  The differential equation itself is simple to solve once you see that the left hand side is the derivative of $h^2(x).$